# Pinescript strategy will plot arrow but not trigger

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have a relatively simple strategy but I noticed that the entry is not triggered on all expected bars.

```
inTradeWindow = time >= backtestStartDate
isLong() =>
    strategy.position_size > 0

//entry conditions
hasCrossed() =>
    high[1] < mid[1] and high > mid and isLong() == false//ta.crossover(high,mid)

plotarrow(hasCrossed() ? 1 : na)

if inTradeWindow and hasCrossed()
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, 1, limit = entryPx)
```

I added a plot arrow check and that works for the same condition.
I have tried customer cross over with no difference.

See the 2nd green up arrow

[image]

Comment: I think I've found the issue.  As I am using a limit price the inner bar is obviously looking for the next time that price is available.  Frustrating.  May have to model this in python instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is due to my use of limit to set the entry price and the tick history is looking for the next time that price is valid after the bar it was triggered on.